# Does ExpandoObject in c# has instance accessor like this?

Tags: c#, .net, expandoobject, dynamicobject

consider I have this simple `c#` code:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.FirstName = "John";
obj.LastName = "Doe";
```

I want to add method which will return full name, `John Doe` in this case.
I know the following line will work, but not sure if it is the best aproach

```
obj.GetFullName = new Func<string>(() => $"{obj.FirstName} {obj.LastName}");
```

Is there any other way to access `dynamic object` instance through the `GetFullName` method?

Comment: I think it's the best you can do.